# authenticate() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to submit this User model, but when I try to create a user, it throws me an error: `authenticate() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments, but 2 were given`. While it throws this error, it successfully creates the user with no password when I check my admin

How can I solve this problem?

Models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser): 

     username = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True) 

     email = models.EmailField(unique=True) 

     phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15) 

  

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 

     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'password'] 

  

     def __str__(self): 

         return "{}".format(self.email)
```

Views.py:

```
def create_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save()

            authenticate(request, user)

            return redirect('Home')

    else:

        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html, {'form':form})
```

Forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForms(forms.Form): 

     username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=70, 

     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", 

     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     last_name = forms.CharField(label="last Name", 

     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     email = forms.EmailField(label="School Email", 

     widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label="School Phone Number", 

     widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     password = forms.CharField(label="Password", 

     widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

     repeat_password = forms.CharField(label="Repeat Password", 

     widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})) 

  

  

     class Meta: 

         model = User 

         fields = ['username', 'password', 'email',  

         'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',  

         'repeat_password']
```

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: What are you trying to do here? At first `form.save()` is called on a ModelForm not on a form made through normal Form class.

Comment: @SunderamDubey After changing my form class from: `Form` to `ModelForm` the error isn't gone. It still shows this error.

Comment: Do you also want to authenticate and login the user in the `create_user` view or simply want to save the form and redirect the user to some page?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I wanted to save the form and redirect user to the Login page sir.

Comment: Also it is `RegistrationForms` you defined and you're using it in the view as `RegistrationForm`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey it was a mistake, because I'm using Stack Overflow with my mobile device.

Comment: Now, you can simply remove `authenticate(request, user)`  and use `form.save()` to save the form, after that redirect the user to `login` page using `return redirect('login')` instead of `return redirect('Home')`. Assuming you have some view with the name `login`.

Comment: Wow, it works, but password isn't save in the database, why? When I try to login the user it's say: `invalid password or Email` and when I check admin, the password Is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need pass user credentials like this...

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            authenticate(request, username=request.POST.get('username'),password=request.POST.get('password'))
            # ------------- OR ----------------
            authenticate(request, username=form.cleaned_data['username'],password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            return redirect('Home')
```